# Can someone explain the difference between these 2 for loops?

Tags: c

```
int n = strlen(s)
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
printf("%c", s[i]);

}

for (int i = 0; i <strlen(s); i++)
{
printf("%c", s[i]);
}
```

What I'm trying to ask is what is happening in memory(under the hood). Let's say the string length is 4, is 4 assigned to n, and would that make it easier for the compiler to compile? In the second code, would the compiler have to check what the string length of s is over and over? Is the point of the first code to make the compiler remember the string length is so it doesn't need to check for it every time. I'm sorry if my question isn't clear enough, telling me how to improve would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Calling `strlen` in a loop like this is theoretically n^2 behavior.  `strlen` is going to loop over all the characters in the string, and then you're calling `strlen` as many times as there are characters in the loop, so for a 10-character string `strlen` ends up looking at 100 total characters.  So calling `strlen` once, outside the loop, can reduce this overhead.  But on the other hand, this kind of optimization (stashing the result of a value, rather than recomputing it every time) is the sort of thing that good compilers can do all by themselves now, so you may not have to worry abut it.

Comment: In the first loop, `strlen` is called _once_. In the 2nd, it is called on _every_ loop. So, if the string length is `n`, the first loop executes in O(n). The 2nd executes in O(n^2).

Comment: The code as it is is likely to compile to the same resulting binary. But you can modify it in such a way that `s` is being (or can be) changed from within the loop. In that case the codes will behave differently.

Comment: _Side note:_ When looping through a string, using a `char *` pointer can be simpler/faster: `for (const char *sp = s;  *sp != 0;  ++sp) printf("%c",*sp);`

Comment: @SteveSummit You're talking about the second for loop, right?

Comment: @EugeneSh. This code is **very unlikelly** to compile to the same binary. Only if compiler knows that `s` is a **string literal** https://godbolt.org/z/q69cze

Comment: The only reason that `strlen` _might_ get optimized to a single call in the second example is because it's defined with `__attribute__((__pure__))`. Or, the compiler will special case `strlen` because it's a "known" function. IMO, it's bad practice to _rely_ on that optimization because many functions are do _not_ have an attribute like that.

Comment: @Anique That's right.

Comment: @0___________ OK, looks like I have overestimated the compilers. But  nothing *prevents* them to optimize this.

Comment: @CraigEstey Excellent point, but you don't even need to use a pointer to "build `strlen` in" to the loop: `for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)`

Comment: @SteveSummit Nice to know that you know how iterate the null character terminated char array (well done - ), but how  is it related to question?

Comment: @0___________ It's related to Craig Etsey's "Side note:" comment above.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I afraid they cant optimize it out - for many reasons.

Comment: @SteveSummit then you need to share the trophy with  Craig Estey

Comment: @0___________ You see the point, though, right? If you're inspecting a string a character at a time, not only do you not need to call `strlen` N times, you don't even need to call it 1 time.

Comment: @SteveSummit No, the question is not : how to iterate the C string only what is the difference between those two for loops.

Comment: @0___________ But sometimes questions attract side comments, of potential interest to the OP.  But now the little SO comment thread watchdog is warning me about extended discussion, so I'm done here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the second code, would the compiler have to check what the string length of s is over and over

That's exactly right. The condition of a `for` loop is evaluated every iteration. Therefore, you should cache the length (or any other result that does not change in each iteration, for that matter).

In this case, as people pointed out, you can do even better avoiding to compute the length since you are iterating the string anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that the first loop will call `strlen` on every iteration.

```
int foo(const char *s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <strlen(s); i++)
    {
        printf("%c", s[i]); 
    }
    return 0;
}

int bar(const char *s)
{
    int n = strlen(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", s[i]);
    }
    return n;
}
```

and the resulting code:

```
foo:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rdi
        push    rbx
        xor     ebx, ebx
        sub     rsp, 8
        jmp     .L2
.L3:
        movsx   edi, BYTE PTR [rbp+0+rbx]
        add     rbx, 1
        call    putchar
.L2:
        mov     rdi, rbp
        call    strlen
        cmp     rax, rbx
        ja      .L3
        add     rsp, 8
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
bar:
        push    r12
        push    rbp
        push    rbx
        mov     rbx, rdi
        call    strlen
        mov     r12, rax
        test    eax, eax
        jle     .L6
        lea     eax, [rax-1]
        lea     rbp, [rbx+1+rax]
.L8:
        movsx   edi, BYTE PTR [rbx]
        add     rbx, 1
        call    putchar
        cmp     rbx, rbp
        jne     .L8
.L6:
        mov     eax, r12d
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        pop     r12
        ret
```

(gcc -O3) https://godbolt.org/z/1oh991

Comment: Add @CraigEstey's  `void baz( const char *s ) { for ( ; *s; s++ ) printf( "%c", *s ); }`  :-)

Comment: @AndrewHenle IMO it is not related to the question. There are more ways: `while(*s)` for example

Comment: Performance is the reason behind this question so IMO it's apropos.  And I'm trying to figure out why the call to `strlen()` doesn't get appear to get optimized out of the loop condition (or my ability to read assembler has gone unused for too long...)